# how to loop through folders specified by text document on batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of folder paths that I want to loop through and get the files and creation date and then send a email notification that these files have been uploaded to the ftp. I have got everything working but I am having trouble looping through the folders to get the files. I think it loops through the text file but by the time i get to my second loop I think it is only looping through the last path that was in the text doc as the variable was getting overwritten.  I tried enclosing the second for statement with parentheses for the first for statement but did not work. Here is my code:

scanFTPCLients.bat

```
 @echo off
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 cls
 @pushd %~dp0
 set i=0
 for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (Pathlist.txt) do (
 set fp=%%i
 set LIST=
 for /r "%fp%" %%a in (*.*) do set i=i+1
 set LIST=!LIST! ---%deptClient%---  %%~na  ----UPLOAD TIME----  %%~ta 
 )
 set LIST=%LIST:~1% 

 IF %i% NEQ 0 (wscript "%~dp0FTPFilesUploadedNotification.vbs")
 popd
```

Pathlist.txt

```
\\vavm\CINICO\Incoming
\\vavm\CIS\Incoming
\\vavm\Forcht\Incoming
\\vavm\HPC\Incoming
\\vavm\K\Incoming
\\vavm\MWEmpCC\Incoming
\\vavm\National Labor Benefits\Incoming
\\vavm\PeriSons\Incoming
\\vavm\US\Incoming
\\vavm\K\Incoming
```

FTPFilesNotification.vbs

```
dim outputArray
dim inputText 
dim message

inputText =  CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%LIST%")

outputArray = split(inputText, "   ")

for each x in outputArray
   message = message & x & vbCRLF
next


Set MyEmail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")

MyEmail.Subject="Clients Imported to System"
MyEmail.From="SYSTEMFUNCTION@mrsllc.org"
MyEmail.To="rickg@gmail.com"
MyEmail.TextBody= "The Following Clients have been imported to the system: " & vbCRLF & message

MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2


MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="mail.org"


MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 

MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate")=1

MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")="username" 

MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")="password"

MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
MyEmail.Send

set MyEmail=nothing
```

Comment: You will need to enclose the second `for` loop in parentheses, but you will also need to use `!path!` to make the delayed expansion work properly. And you will need to change `set i=i+1` to something like `set /a i=!i!+1`. You might need to change the last %LIST%s to !LIST! - but maybe not.

Comment: I recommend not to use variable name `PATH` as this is reserved -- see `path` command...

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, the last `%LIST%` is not set and read in the same block of code, so `!LIST!` is not required (although it would not harm)...

Comment: I have tried enclosing the 2nd for loop within the first for loop before, but I got the error that the full path of  is too long..... I have edited the question to include all my files

Comment: I have set "i" as just a counter to let me know if any files in the folder, If it is not equal to zero it will call the vbs script.  I want to be able to scan the folders in the pathlist text one by one. I am doing this because for each folder I will set a dept client variable set to each filepath that will let me be able to distinguish which client the file came from in my vbscript.

Answer (score 1):

Changed. Not sure what you want to do about sending lines (one at a time or send all when done). If one at a time, integrate into this. If all at once at end, then send output to a temp file and send it.

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
set /A Cnt=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (Pathlist.txt) do (
   echo i= %%i
   for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`Dir /s /b %%i\*.*`) do (
      echo %%~na - %%~ta
      set /A Cnt+=1
   )
) 
echo(Cnt=%Cnt%
pause
popd
```

Comment: unfortunately i tried this and it just opens and closes the cmd box doesn't do anything

Comment: I should have caught that. Don't use path as that is an environment variable. Change all occurrences of path to MyPath or something like that. Not sure what you are doing with the last half of the script... but I get paths echoed. Also verify that Pathlist.txt has valid data in it.

Comment: I get  the full path of is too long, I don't understand how its too long, if I copy one of the lines from the text document and enter in the for statement in place of the variable , the code works fine

Comment: We don't want to step on the Windows environment variable named Path and we don't need that anyway. See my changed answer above. Goth rid of path and use %%I to specify full path in FOR loop.

Comment: The edited code you provided does nothing... my code works when I remove the 2nd for loop out of the 1st for loop, but It only gets the files from the last path, I understand that the 2nd loop has to be within the first loop, but when I do I get the file path of (blank) is too long. I dont understand how its too long because if I take the path directly from the text file and place instead of the variable it works.

Comment: Changed but more to do. See above.

Answer (score 1):

For comparison, in PowerShell, it could be:

```powershell
$emailSettings = @{
    From = "you@example.org"
    To = "you@example.org"
    Subject = "Upload report"
    SmtpServer = "yourmailserver"
}

$report = dir -Path @(gc pathlist.txt) | select FullName, CreationTime
Send-MailMessage @emailSettings -Body "$($report|ConvertTo-Html)" -BodyAsHtml
```

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to loop through files in vbscript

```
'On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dirname = InputBox("Enter Dir name")
'Searchterm = Inputbox("Enter search term")
ProcessFolder DirName

Sub ProcessFolder(FolderPath)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)

    Set Fls = fldr.files

    For Each thing in Fls
'        Set contents = thing.OpenAsTextStream
'        If err.number = 0 then
'            If Instr(contents.readall, searchterm) > 1 then msgbox thing.path
'        Else
'            err.clear
'        End If
         msgbox Thing.Name & " " & Thing.DateLastModified 



    Next

    Set fldrs = fldr.subfolders
    For Each thing in fldrs
        ProcessFolder thing.path
    Next

End Sub
```

To send mail

```
Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
emailObj.From     = "dc@gail.com"

emailObj.To       = "dc@gail.com"

emailObj.Subject  = "Test CDO"
emailObj.TextBody = "Test CDO"

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration
msgbox emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")    = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")      = true 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")    = "YourUserName"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")    = "Password1"
emailConfig.Fields.Update

emailObj.Send

If err.number = 0 then Msgbox "Done"
```

To read a file line by line

```
On Error Resume Next
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File = Fso.CreateTextFile("C:\myfile.txt", True)
If err.number <> 0 then
    Wscript.Echo "Error: " & err.number & " " & err.description & " from " & err.source
    err.clear
    wscript.exit
End If
Do Until File.AtEndOfStream
    Msgbox File.readline
Loop
```